# Recovering KVM domain configuration file

Tags: configuration, domain, kvm-virtualization

I undefined a domain that led to deletion of domain configuration file. However, the disk image that configuration was referring to still exists. I am wondering if it's possible to recover the deleted file? Alternatively, how can I redefine domain back with reference to existing disk image?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the filesystem but I'd say that there is no way to recover the file. It's easier to define the virtual machien again using the disk image that you have. It's not clear what configuration tool are you using to manage VMs. We could help you if you give us that information.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the VM again, and instead of creating a new disk image, simply point the new VM to the existing disk. In some cases, it is important to make sure you set up the hardware right though - the NIC types, and especially the disk controller really make a difference here